# How to deal with a 2x2 experimental design if the dependent variable is dichotomous?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, experiment-design, repeated-measures

I am assessing the acceptability of a sentence in a within-subjects design with two crossed factors (type of sentence, missing word). After reading each sentence, the participants answer a simple yes/no question which is my dependent variable.

Because a dichotomous variable is not normally distributed I am guessing I can't use an ANOVA, what is my alternative? 
I want to test which group of sentences is less/more acceptable than the others.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use a mixed effects model treating `subject` as a random effect, `type_of_sentence` and `missing_word` as fixed effects, and specifying the binomial error family. Search this site for mixed effect models for more detail.